# One of three users can't work on access DB

Tags: microsoft-access

I'm having a problem with a costumer after a recent change.
Situation before the change:
- 3 PCs in a workgroup: PCs 1 and 2 are WIN10, PC3 WIN7
- PC 1 has an acceess DB (rather small 60MB) in a shared folder
- PCs 1, 2 and 3 can work (make changes to existing records, create new ones) simultaneously with no issues at all

Change: PC3 got thrown out and was replaced with a new WIN10 machine.

Situation after the change: 
- PCs 1 and 2 can still work on the DB like before
- PC 3 can open the DB from the share, but none of the changes made by users on PCs 1 and 2 are visible here. 
- Changes done by PC3 are also not visible for users on PCs 1 and 2
- Even if the DB is copied from the share and pasted to PC3 localy, the changes done won't show up

I've tried to find the reason for this but with no success. The mode the DB is opened is none exclusive.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you have the correct Access Drivers installed in all 3 machines? Open `ODBCAD32` and check the drivers are all present and correct.

Comment: DB isn't [split](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/split-an-access-database-3015ad18-a3a1-4e9c-a7f3-51b1d73498cc) (Frontend/Backend)? Mapped drive or  UNC path? Check link to share with db, if mapped use UNC.

Comment: Drivers are installed correctly. Also DB is not split. Have tried via mapped drive, UNC, mklinked folder and just a copy of the DB locally. Nothing works. None of the changes are showing.

Comment: I solved it. It was an obscure link within the DB to a local path that did not exist on the newly installed machine.